# Adding a scheduled task using the COM API without a password?

Tags: winapi, com

I've attempted to add a scheduled task using the COM API but I have not been successful without providing the user password. I guess that I could ask for the password if there's absolutely no other way to do it. However, I know OneDrive adds scheduled tasks and I have never seen it ask me for a password. Of course OneDrive is written by Microsoft but presumably whatever API they are using, I can use as well.

I'm currently using the `RegisterTask` OLE method to submit XML and when `ValidateOnly` is enabled, I receive no errors. It's only when I actually try to submit the task that nothing happens, and if I provide a password it works. However, as I said, I feel that there has to be some way to register the task without a password.

Comment: Presumably OneDrive runs a service which has sufficient rights

Comment: You can browse all tasks in your system, just run the "task scheduler" app. Then, if you click on the root "Task Scheduler Library", you will be able to analyse how tasks like OneDrive, Google Chrome Update, Adobe Acrobat Update, etc are defined. You can even export taks as XML (and import them https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/14/working-with-task-scheduler-xml/). Plus the XML has a 1:1 relation with the API. I think most tasks like these just use "run when user is logged on", w/o any specific credential